# Is <bean:define> and <c:set> the same in Java Struts?

Tags: java, struts

I need some help. I'm learning struts. Is `bean:define` and `c:set` similar in Java Struts? If not, how they can be differentiated?

Comment: [c:set doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) and [bean:define doc](http://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/bean/define.html)

Answer (score 0):

`<bean:define>` define a scripting variable based on the value of the specified bean property, while the `<c:set>` tag is JSTL-friendly version of the `setProperty` action, used for assigning a value to an object or variable within a specified scope.